# How to set shortcut key for closing the project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-project-file

Windows>preference>general>keys>close project. After going through the above path I have set 'binding' field as 'Alt+C'. But what should I select in 'when' field ?
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beadq.jpg)

Comment: "In Windows" probably

Comment: What Greg says. With _Editing Text_ the shortcut would only available when the focus is e.g. in a text editor, but not when the focus is e.g. in the _Project Explorer_ view. _In Windows_ means independent where the focus is (except dialogs or when there is the same shortcut for a more specific _When_).